# Linux move files from specific directory one directory up and delete empty folder

Tags: linux, unix, script, mv

I need to move files out from a directory inside a directory inside a directory and remove folder that I move them from. I would need a recursive script. The directory structure:

```
/Folder0/Alphabetic_folder/Folder_name/DeleteFolder

/Folder0/A/Folder1/DeleteFolder
/Folder0/B/Folder2/DeleteFolder
```

`DeleteFolder` always has the same name which is `info`. I would need something like:

1. go inside directory (alphabetic)
2. for all folders there go inside, if there is an `info` folder `mv *.*` to the current folder, remove `info` (that would be: `mv info/* ./ && rm info`)
3. if `info` is not there exit folder
4. move to the next folder

I am sure that this is a trivial problem with some script skills, but my script skill are low in this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPD.
that will work better :)

```
find -depth -print0 |  while read -d '' -r dir; do if [[ $dir == *info ]]; then mv "$dir"/* /tmp; rmdir "$dir"; fi; done
```

old answer here:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /Folder0
for i in `ls`; do #get list of files and dirs in a folder0
    if [ -d $i ]; then #if list item is a folder
    cd $i   #then go inside (in you ex its folder A)
    for j in `ls`; do #list folders and files
            if [ -d $j ]; then #if item is folder
                    cd $j            #go inside (in your ex - Folder1)
                    mv info/* /any_folder_you_want #it will not move files if there is an error
                    rmdir info/ #it will not remove dir if it is not empty
                    cd .. #(go down)
            fi #(go to the next folder Folder2)
    done;  #end of folder A
    cd ..  #go down 
    fi     #next folder B...
done
```

You have to change part with mv and rmdir for testing that you are getting right results
just put ls there and comment lines with mv and rmdir:

```
#mv info/* /any_folder_you_want #it will not move files if there is an error
ls
#rmdir info/ #it will not remove dir if it is not empty
```

you have to run this script outside Folder1.

questions?

Comment: folders inside A,B,C with space are not affected: Folder0/A/A - copy/info

Comment: find -depth -print0 |  while read -d '' -r dir; do if [[ $dir == *info ]]; then mv "$dir"/* /tmp; rmdir "$dir"; fi; done

Comment: /tmp should be "$dir/../" and then it works like it should. Thanks you for the help

Answer (score 1):

Assuming search is for all alpha directories from the working directory:

```
dirs=$(find [a-z][A-Z]* -type d -name info) 
for f in $dirs; do echo "$f/*" done     # first test it works to requirements

for f in $dirs; do mv "$f/*" "$f"/..; rmdir "$f"; done # working version with mv and rmdir
```